# HTML - Accessibility in icons and apple-touch-icon

Tags: accessibility, apple-touch-icon

I'm currently working at improving the accessibility of a site.
I'm using the TotalValidator tool to check the accessibility issues there, and the icons on the

The icons there use this format:

```
<link href="/full/path/to/the/image/120.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" />
<link href="/full/path/to/the/image/152.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" />
<link href="/full/path/to/the/image/167.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="167x167" />
<link href="/full/path/to/the/image/180.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" />
<link href="/full/path/to/the/image/192.png" rel="icon" sizes="192x192" />
<link href="/full/path/to/the/image/128.png" rel="icon" sizes="128x128" />
```

I searched about this topic and this format seems to be correct, but the accessibility report throws:

> The 'sizes' attribute is not allowed here.

Does anyone knows how I should replace it? Thank you!

Comment: According to the [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/document-metadata.html#the-link-element), `sizes` is a valid `link` attribute. I do not see any issues with your example, so I suggest contacting the TotalValidator support.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for refer to the doc.
Maybe the sizes attribute is valid for rel="icon", but not for rel="apple-touch-icon"?

Comment: Checking the doc, you're right: https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/document-metadata.html#the-link-element
Probably the tool is a little bit outdated for this case. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @Darek Kay, [this documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/document-metadata.html#the-link-element) refers that:

> The sizes attribute gives the sizes of icons for visual media. [...]
> The attribute must not be specified on link elements that do not have a rel attribute that specifies the icon keyword or the apple-touch-icon keyword.
>
> NOTE: The apple-touch-icon keyword is a registered extension to the
> predefined set of link types, but user agents are not required to
> support it in any way.

Thank you!